# Timer based on Express JS GET/POST events

Tags: node.js, express, settimeout, ejs

I am completely lost on this one.  I have a simple app that asks 6 questions to a user.  Each question and the answers available are shown on a dynamically generated view for a particular questions route.  I want to set up a time that works as follows:  When question 1 shows, the user has 5 minutes to answer all 6 questions.  The timer would clear once the POST for question 6 occurs.

The basis for the GET/POST code is as follows (using the ejs model):

```
app.get('/survey/:question_number?', restrict, routes.survey);
app.post('/survey/:question_number', function(req, res) {
  //question code
}
```

Here is the export route code:

```
exports.survey = function(req, res) {
  //Question logic to pass to the render
  res.render('question', {
    info : info
  });
}
```

For the html, it simply uses the passed "info" to generate the questions and answers and then uses a standard form method=post to send the answer selected back to the app.post.

Can anyone recommend a good method to accomplish this that is not overly complex?  Thanks!

Comment: Why you need timer on `ExpressJS` (server side)? You have to do this in client side with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. If you still need this from server side, you need a server push with help of `websockets` using `socket.IO` etc which will make things complex. Easy one is go with the client side scripting.

Comment: Can you show an example of how that would look with this example?

Comment: Any client side scripting are you using like `jquery`, `angular` etc?

Comment: No.  This is a simple example of Express JS, EJS for rendering and then standard javascript/html.

Comment: Can you post all the relevant `JS` and `html` piece, so it will be easy to update your code, instead of giving you a full working code?

Comment: I will update the post with more of the baseline code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use sessions for this task. After the first question is requested you set a session variable, that will indicate the time, when all questions must be answered. After that you just compare this variable value with a current time of a request. I guess it's one of the most simplest approaches to solve your task.

Comment: That was my original thought as well.  The issue is that I am already establishing a session when the user logs in to the page.  The session exists even when the survey is over and they are looking at the results.  I couldn't figure out a way to kill the timeout after the survey ends without effecting the current session.

Comment: You don't need a timeout. When you start this survey or quiz, you need to set a variable in session, that will hold future (deadline) timestamp, when this survey or quiz will be invalid. So if I start on Fri Nov 11 2016 03:36:09, then survey should be invalid on Fri Nov 11 2016 03:41:09. And in every request you check whether current timestamp is not greater than deadline timestamp. If it's less than deadline, the quiz can still work, but if not - the quiz should be stopped.

Comment: That makes sense, but what happens with the use case where the user sits on the last question for 30 minutes?  No request is made, so the deadline is never evaluated and the quiz remains open, despite it being way beyond the limit.  That is why I wanted it to be an internal timeout countdown clock.

Comment: You can set the timer value in session variable and use that as timer in your view and then evaluate whether the quiz should be stopped or continued even if he waits for 30 minutes on last question client side timer won't allow it to do so and stop the test

Comment: Do you know an example of this I can look at or could someone write up something based on my baseline I have above...?